# Full video background height of video is extending beyond 100%;

Tags: html, css, html5-video

video is not perfectly 100% it is extending beyond 100% ? I used absolute positioning but video's height is about 110% instead of 100%?

```
html, body {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0; }

        section {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%; 
        }

        section video {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          min-width: 100%;
          min-height: 100%;
        }
```

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] of your problem?

Comment: Can you share entire code HTML and CSS. that will help more. if not just try using position: relative to .section class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set max-width of video. You can combine max-width and min-width to width and same for height. Try this code

```
section video{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```